# How to load dynamic external components into Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, plugins, webpack, runtime

I'm facing a problem with Angular application.

I would like to have an angular application written in Typscript build with (aot).

The aim is to display a user dashboard with some widgets. A widget is an angular component.

My app comes with some embedded widgets.
But widgets should be extended by something like a market place; or created manually.

The market should download files (js/ts/bunlde..??) into a specific folder.

Then my app should be able to load the new widgets (= ng component) and instanciate them.

My folder structure (production)

```
  |- index.html
  |- main.f5b448e73f5a1f3f796e.bundle.js
  |- main.f5b448e73f5a1f3f796e.bundle.js.map
  |- .... (all other files generated)
  |- externalWidgets
      |- widgetA
            |- widjetA.js
            |- widjetA.js.map
            |- assets
                 |- image.png
      |- widgetB
            |- widjetB.ts
            |- widjetB.html
            |- widjetB.css
```

Then when loading the user page, the database say that there is a widgetA.
So the aim is to dynamically load files and instanciate included component.

I've tried many solutions, using "require" and "System.import" but both fails when the path to load is dynamically generated.

Is this should be possible ?
I can change my code structure; change external widgets.. (for example widgetB is not yet transpiled,...)

In fact I'm looking for a "plugin system" with an Angular4/webpack application.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm doing exactly the same. And I explain the details in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pERhnBBae2k) at NgConf.

The first thing to understand is that Webpack cannot dynamically load modules that are unknown during build time. This is inherent to the way Webpack builds dependency tree and collects modules identifiers during build time. And it's perfectly fine since Webpack is a modules bundler, not modules loader. So you need to use a module loader and the only viable option now is SystemJS.

Then, each plugin should be packaged as a module and all exported components should be added to the `entryComponents` of that module.

During runtime, you will load that module to get access to the components declared inside if it. You don't really need a module but that's a unit of packaging in Angular so you can't avoid using it. Now, once you get a module, you have to options depending on whether the module is built using AOT or not.

If it's built using AOT, you just get the exported factory class from the module and create a module instance:

```
System.import('path/to/module').then((module)=>{
    const moduleFactory = module.moduleFactoryClassName;
    const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.parentInjector);
    const resolver = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver;
    const compFactory = resolver.resolveComponentFactory(AComponent);
}
```

If it's not built using AOT, you have to compile it using JIT compiler:

```
System.import('path/to/module').then((module)=>{
    const moduleFactory = this.compiler.compileModuleSync(module.moduleClassName);
    const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.parentInjector);
    const resolver = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver;
    const compFactory = resolver.resolveComponentFactory(AComponent);
}
```

Then you can add dynamic components wherever you want using techniques described in this article: [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: your approach is very interesting, is that possible using this way to import a remotely hosted component/module ?

Comment: @Seb, yes, but you need to use SystemJS for that

Comment: great that could do the trick for me ! have you any example of how to integrate systemJs and webpack ? And an example of a System.import of a remote component ?

Comment: do you use angular-cli?

Comment: Yes I do, should i use something else ?

Comment: @Seb, create a new question and post a question here, I'll take a look later

Comment: Thanks @AngularInDepth.com, here it is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321477/get-and-load-a-remote-component-module-in-an-angular-4-4-app

Comment: It's not possible to combine SystemJs with Angular-Cli. Am I wrong? @AngularInDepth.com

Comment: You can not load an umd library created by rollup and loaded as a script because it is not able to find its own angular classes @AngularInDepth.com

Comment: @user3757628, it depends on how you bundle everything together. If you bundle in UMD bundle, SystemJS will pick it up

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com the only problem is that angular is not able to solve the path where the library is, for example @angular/core

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com hello again, I have created a repository with advances in this topic, but I have an error that I am unable to solve. Could you help me? https://github.com/xino1010/angular-external-modules

Comment: @user3757628, can you maybe create a separate question with details?

Comment: of course @AngularInDepth.com
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312031/error-importing-external-angular-module-at-runtime

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com you use CLI to package it as UMD too ? or are you not doing that? and if not how would you handle the vendor, inline and main bundle files? Is there any progress on this already?

Comment: _Then, each plugin should be packaged as a module and all exported components should be added to the entryComponents of that module._ - Is this as UMD? @AngularInDepth.com

Comment: Btw nice solution, but AComponent is not 'known' yet so how can you then make a hard reference to its class name? Thanks

Comment: @LarsMeijdam, I'm not using CLI. But the newest CLI should have library support. I haven't looked at it yet. Yes, `AComponent` is not known, so the components should be defined as providers and later retrieved from the injector. Watch this talk about this approach https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pERhnBBae2k

Comment: Thanks! Already in my watch later! clear, I actually noticed while building the app for production it is still making chunk files with the use of the angular cli. I'm trying to extend routing with loadChildren and then system.import, but that is creating chunk files (which i dont want), now I try using http.get to fetch the umd bundle and add it dynamically, but loadChildren is not accepting that :(

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Interesting talk done by you! nice to see you put  a lot of effort in reverse engineering this loading mechanism. I was wondering if you faced challenges to inject extension modules during runtime (by extending the route with a new loadChildren) after adding the .js files to the index.html (in runtime) ?

Comment: The reason why I ask is because the company i now work at creates 'shippable' software which runs on premise, they want to extend periodically but don't want to 'recompile' the entire application on premise

Comment: @LarsMeijdam, to inject a new route you need to use `resetRoute` API. I hope I'll find time to write an article some time in the future.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Thanks for your response! I've tried and use that indeed! and its working, only thing is while building the application is creating chunk files for every route mentioned in the loadchildren of resetConfig(), which is something I dont want, because it might be a module which is not 'there' yet, I've found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590455/angular-5-load-modules-that-are-not-known-at-compile-time-dynamically-at-run in the meantime to try out! Thanks!

Comment: I created a repository on github with a solution which might help. It uses Angular 6 libraries and 1 base applications which load up the UMD bundled libraries lazily; https://github.com/lmeijdam/angular-umd-dynamic-example

If you have any suggestions, please feel free to add!

PS: it's far from perfect, but it is at least loading 'unknown' libraries during run-time. Need to look for an 'eval' alternative

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi looking at angular 8 it looks like NgModuleFactoryLoader was deprecated and replaced with a dynamic "import" function.  IE import('src/app/somemodule/some.module').then(..).  Any idea if "import" has support for loading modules from external servers?